# What is num_ref_idx_l0_active_minus1?

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, libav

I'm encoding an h264 file and the ouput PPS contains `num_ref_idx_l0_active_minus1=3`, but I need this to be 0 instead.

In the [ITU-T H.264 spec](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-H.264-201610-I/en), it states :

> num_ref_idx_l0_active_minus1 specifies the maximum reference index for
>   reference picture list 0 that shall be used to decode the slice.

But the closest option I can find in `libx264` is `-refs`, but that doesn't seem to affect it.

I understand that since this is referring to List 0, it is associated with B-Frames, but there are no specific `libx264` parameters relevant to that specific field.

Comment: "--refs 1" (param.i_frame_reference = 1) should result in num_ref_idx_l0_default_active_minus1 equal to 0.

Comment: yep, you are correct, i originally thought that was only affecting `num_ref_frames` in SPS, but after i tried it it does indeed work...